# How to print by using For loop?

Tags: equation-solving, programming, list-manipulation

```
For[mu = 0; mu < 6, mu++, 
 mu = -4.84*10^(-4) - 17.82*10^(-4)*T1 + 
  1.53*10^(-4)*T1*2.303*Log[T1]; Print[T1]]
```

I want to get the value of `T1` for values of mu up to 5. How can I get them?

Comment: `T1` doesn't change inside the loop? Perhaps `Monitor` is what you are looking for.

Comment: can you please explain. and no T1 doesnot cahnge inside the loop

Comment: Inside your for-loop you use a parameter T1 , which isn't influenced by the for-loop.

Comment: so what can i do now?

Comment: Inside your for-loop should be a line `T1=...` which evaluates a new T1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for. It is the best I can do when trying to guess what you really want to compute. My goal here is show you how your For-loop can be fixed, rather than to instruct you in the better methods available to solve your problem.

```
For[mu = 0, mu < 6, mu++,
 sol =
   Quiet @ NSolve[
             mu == -4.84*10^(-4) - 17.82*10^(-4) T1 + 1.53*10^(-4) 2.303 T1 Log[T1],
             T1]; 
   Print[mu, "  ", (T1 /. sol) // First]]
```

When evaluated the above code prints

[image: soln]

Notes

1. There are syntax errors in your code. `mu = 0; ...` should be `mu = 0, ...`, and `mu = -4.84*10^(-4) - 17.82*10^(-4)*T1 + 1.53*10^(-4)*T1*2.303*Log[T1]` is not a request to solve an equation, it is assignment to the variable `mu`.
2. To solve for `T1` at each iteration is a more complicated process. I show you a method using `NSolve`. Bob Hanlon shows you another way to do it.
3. I use `Quiet` to suppress some warning messages issued by `NSolve`, because I think they would alarm you more than they inform you.

Answer (score 3):

[`For`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) is generally avoided as inefficient. Using a pure [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) with [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

```
data = T1 /. 
     Solve[# == -4.84*10^(-4) - 17.82*10^(-4)*T1 + 
         1.53*10^(-4)*T1*2.303*Log[T1], T1][[1]] & /@ Range[0, 5] // Quiet

(* {158.54, 1329.7, 2164.72, 2915.71, 3619.49, 4291.32} *)
```

Plotting the results

```
ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> {0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {mu, T1}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, using [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

```
data2 = Table[
   T1 /. Solve[
      mu == -4.84*10^(-4) - 17.82*10^(-4)*T1 + 1.53*10^(-4)*T1*2.303*Log[T1], 
      T1][[1]], {mu, 0, 5}] // Quiet

(* {158.54, 1329.7, 2164.72, 2915.71, 3619.49, 4291.32} *)
```

The different methods provide identical results

```
data === data2

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `T1`doesn't change inside the for-loop.

Here I give a working version

```
 For[mu = 0, mu < 6,mu++, -4.84*10^(-4) - 17.82*10^(-4)*T1 + 1.53*10^(-4)*T1*2.303*Log[T1]; Print[T1]]
```

which prints `T1` 6 times.

Comment: but i need the value of T1 for different values of mu=0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: There is no calculation inside your for -loop which changes `T1` !!!

Comment: so what should be the program for that?

Comment: You should know that! Is the expression `mu = -4.84*10^(-4) - 17.82*10^(-4)*T1 + 
  1.53*10^(-4)*T1*2.303*Log[T1]`  an equation which must be solved for T1?